# Remove padding from bottom of div with text in it

Tags: html, css

I'm using twitter-bootstrap and all I have is a div with some text in it so far, but I can't seem to figure out how to take the padding off of the bottom. I tried `padding-bottom:0px;` but that didn't do anything. Ideally, I'd like to change my element from looking like this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row header text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 title">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get rid of the bottom of the green element (.header)?

```
.header {
    background:green;
}

.title {
    color:white;
    font-size:600%;
}
```

Comment: You're asking a styling question but showing us the html which does no good. I'm suspecting this will have everything to do with margin on the text.

Comment: @Rob yeah, I didn't really see much point in posting the css since its just changing the font size and background colour, I tried changing .title to have `margin:0px;` is that what you meant?

Comment: Still would help to see your CSS...

Comment: @SpencerKillen Would it be acceptable to simply have the banner be the same height, and only use `vertical-align: bottom;` to achieve the same effect?

Comment: No. We need to know what all those classes are doing and not doing.

Comment: The CSS you added is not showing the problem.

Comment: That is all the css... And bootstrap

Comment: I guess this is just a problem of  `line-height`

Answer (score 3):

That space is not padding; It belongs to the lowercase letters having descenders like (qypj).

A workaround would be wrapping the text by a `<span>`

```
<div class="col-xs-12 title">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

And then align the `<span>` element vertically as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/noxuy/1/watch?html,css,output)**

```css
.title { font-size: 3em; }

.title span {
    height: 1em; /* 1em is equal to the font-size of the parent which is 3em */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Too much html to get a simple thing accomplished.

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/cadil/1/edit**

HTML

```
  <div class="my-title">
          <span>Text</span>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.my-title {
    background: green;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.my-title span {
    padding-top: 15px;
    display: block;
    line-height: .65;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This is not scalable.

Comment: Changing the `line-height` to `.65` and adding `padding-top: 15px;` works in this case but it may not work on different fonts.